# Possible to retrieve NSSet with variables from NSSet with objects?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsarray, nsset

If you have an NSSet with objects of type car.
Car has two properties: NSString *name, NSInteger speed
You want an NSSet containing only NSStrings for the car names.

How can I do this without iterating over every object and putting it in a mutable set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [key value coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000107-SW1).

```
NSSet *namesOfCars = [setOfCars valueForKeyPath:@"name"];
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason you chose `valueForKeyPath:` over `valueForKey:` in this case?

Comment: My original test code was using a [collection operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE) which requires `valueForKeyPath:`. So for this example, no specific reason.